# Title of unanswered page cannot be translated

Tags: bug, status-review, localization, international-sites, transifex

On SO.ja, select "[スコア (Score)](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=votes)" order on the [question list page](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/unanswered), the page title "Highly scored unanswered question" cannot be translated.

[Bug report on ja.SO meta](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3752)

I've already added translations to traducir.win and transifex and have updated the site footer revision several times, but the translations are not reflected.

- https://ja.traducir.win/strings/15866
- https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ja/translate/#ja/english/410353282

[image]

Comment: I'm unable to repro, but maybe I'm looking at the wrong thing. At `https://ja.stackoverflow.com/unanswered`, I do see the same thing you translated on the title. [Here is a screenshot](https://gervas.io/translation.png). If that's not it, please get me the exact url. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe some local cache?

Comment: I also confirmed that the translation is now applied. But, I reported the issue over a month ago and it wasn't applied until the end of August. ( [New bug reports from community users.](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3760) ) Normally, the translation should be applied within a few days, so it seems that some kind of problem occurred in the past month.

Comment: Next time it might be helpful to ping @g3rv4 , cubick. So he can read your reply above mine here.

Comment: @Luuklag is correct,  and the question still remains: what caused it not to work originally. Local cache, in which case there's nothing to do, or some glitch that the developer might track down and prevent from happening again.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard or someone forgot to push the new translation?

Comment: translations should be automatically pushed... if it took a month, that's def an issue I'd love to investigate. Unfortunately, I'm not aware of any translation in this state. Next time this happens please ping me either on chat or on the traducir repo (opening an issue)

Comment: Looking at the [translation history](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ja/translate/#ja/english/410353282) , the push from traducir to transifex was also done a month ago. I think there was a problem with the applied on the site. / @g3rv4 Are they only pinging you to report problems with traducir?

Comment: yes, traducir is at this point a personal project. We have plans to move it to the Stack Overflow realm, but until that happens... I'm the person to ping

Comment: For the record, I would like to clarify two points. 1. This is not a Traducir issue. Because it is immediately reflected in Transifex 2. This is not a local cache issue. I've tracked this issue for a month.

Comment: @g3rv4 Please post what you know so far as an answer instead of just re-tagging it. / [I told you in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/61922383#61922383) , There are several other places where the translation is not applied, and the fundamental problem has not been resolved.

Comment: you've provided exactly what we needed for investigating this further. I was on vacation and that's why I didn't reply, but I'm back now.

Comment: alright, added an answer that explains what I know and what we're doing about it. I'll keep it updated as I hear more

Comment: @cubick any chance you know of another string that's translated but not appearing on the site?

Answer (score 7):

cubick has provided what we needed to look into this issue further. That is: [a translated string](https://ja.traducir.win/strings/12816) that's [not being updated on the site](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/90894/flask%e3%83%9c%e3%82%bf%e3%83%b3%e3%81%a7python%e5%ae%9f%e8%a1%8c%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84). What's different about this string than the one in the original answer is that this one is currently live.

I've confirmed that:

- The translation is making it from Traducir into Transifex (cubick had already verified that)
- Our build pipeline is pulling that translation from Transifex and putting it into the right database: [image: SSMS screenshot]
- After we build, the translation isn't being properly applied

I've raised this to the teams that work in this area, and I'll keep you posted.

Comment: "the translation isn't being properly applied" - but you wrote comment on the question that you can't repro, i.e. it's working fine by now. So it means sometimes it's fine and sometimes not?

Comment: what I couldn't repro was the original question (the title on that particular page, "Highly scored unanswered questions"). Now, this translation ("A community member has associated this post with a similar question.") is visible [here](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/90894/flask%e3%83%9c%e3%82%bf%e3%83%b3%e3%81%a7python%e5%ae%9f%e8%a1%8c%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84)

Comment: I see Japanese there, so guess it's some server side cache per user?

Comment: it's translated now :(